# How to put my for-loop and range output into a list and display only certain logic text?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, integer, range

I have a piece of code here where I am creating a logic to be displaying all of the numbers from 2, to my `int(input)` to be converted to a `list` and then *only* display the prime numbers from 2 to my input.

Here is my code:

```
def display_prime_numbers(maximum):
    lst = []
    if maximum <= 2:
        print('Enter Number Greater Than 2')
    maximum = maximum + 1
    rng = range(2,maximum)
    for index in rng:
        print(index, end=' ')
    for i in rng:
        if (index % i) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            print(f'{index} is a prime number')
```

This is my output:

```
Enter Positive Integer Greater Than 2:10
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Summary: I'm unable to display my range count loop as a `list` and am trying to *only* display my prime number pieces.

i.e. expected:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

3 is a prime number
5 is a prime number
7 is a prime number
```

Comment: Your return False statement will kick out of the function before the rest of the loop runs.
You could delete it and just print if index % i != 0

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my comment, your return false statement will end the function. The first time the mod of the index is == 0, then the function will end and the rest of the list will not be evaluated for being prime.

```
def display_prime_numbers(maximum):
lst = []
if maximum <= 2:
    print('Enter Number Greater Than 2')
maximum = maximum + 1
rng = range(2,maximum)
for index in rng:
    print(index, end=' ')
for i in rng:
    if (index % i) != 0: #Just print here!
        print(f'{index} is a prime number')
display_prime_numbers(10)
```